# How can we pass less parameters than the method require us to do using DataProvider?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

How can we pass less parameters than the method require us to do using DataProvider?

I will try to explain, let say for an example i created a Method called fetchData(string objectype,string object value, String locatortype,String locatorValue,String message);

I am retrieving the data from the Excel file, on its first line i am passing only two parameters not all five of them using DataProvider annotation, only on the fourth line i am passing all the parameters as the Method demands.I didn't encounter any error,it works perfectly fine.

my understanding is this, you cannot pass less parameters than the method requires you to do,apparently it possible using DataProvider annotation,but how?

```
className.perform(row.getCell(1), row.getCell(2),row.getCell(3), row.getCell(4));
```

There is no data in the 2 and the 3 columns of the first row in the ExcelFile

```
perform(GOTOURl,'','',URL) 

public static void perform(String operation, String objectName, String objectType, String val)
{
    System.out.println("");
    switch (operation.toUpperCase())
    {
        case "CLICK":
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType)).click();
            break;
        case "SETTEXT":
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType)).sendKeys(val);
            break;
        case "GOTOURL":
            driver.get(p.getProperty(val));
            break;
        case "GETTEXT":
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(p, objectName, objectType)).getText();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass less parameters then a method requires. That is why many APIs have additional methods which pass default values. But if they are not there, you'll have to define these 'default values' yourself.

Comment: Does this question actually (directly) relate to Selenium in any way? If not, please edit the question and remove the selenium and selenium-webdriver tags.

Comment: Hi,there! Yes,Bobulous, i am talking about Selenium Web driver using TestNG dataProvider annotation.

Comment: You might need to edit your question to include a code sample (as little code as is needed to demonstrate the problem/question) to give us a better idea of how your pieces fit together.

Comment: Okay Bobulous, i will do that, thanks.

Comment: M le Rutte Hi, Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still passing all 4 parameters, it's just that `objectName` and `objectType` are passed as empty string.